# why does this for-loop only output once?

Tags: loops, for-loop, console.log

- SOLVED in the comments, thanks guys! *

My first post. Thanks in advance.

why does my for loop only out 3 when i console.log(i)?
Isn't it supposed to output:
1,3,5,7,9?

```
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) continue; 
}
console.log(i)
```

Best
Jesper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `console.log` is outside the scope of your for loop. You most likely have `i` defined elsewhere and set to 3. if it were in the `for loop`, it would post your expected results.

```js
//example 1
var i = 3

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) continue; 
}
console.log(i) 


//example 2


for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) continue; 
  console.log(i) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Josh! It worked :D 
Have a great day sir!